# How can I show a block above the layer which I've darkened

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have the settings layout. I should blur the background and show a block, where I advise the person to update the app if the version is not the last one. I have already tried many things, but it did not work. I do not know is it one block that does it or not. The block should contain text and two buttons: update and cancel like at the picture. If they are two different ways to solve, please provide both options...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WindowManager` to draw views over (any) app. However, the background in the picture is not blurred it is dimmed.

To use the `WindowManager` you need to enable this permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <application
        ...
```

Then you can create the layout to display the warning, for example `warning.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/warning"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_close_warning"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="CLICK ME"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And now in your `Settings` Activity, you can use the `WindowManager` to create the view:

```
public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int TAG_PERMISSION_OVERLAY = 10;

    private View warning;
    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private WindowManager.LayoutParams params;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        createWarningWithPermission();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        createWarningWithPermission();
    }

    private void createWarningWithPermission(){
        // permission only needed for SDK version 23 and later
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
             // checks if application has the permission to draw the view over apps
             if(android.provider.Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)){
                createWarning();
             }else{
                // redirects the user to app settings where he/she can enable the permission
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:"+ BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID));
                startActivityForResult(intent, TAG_PERMISSION_OVERLAY);
             }
        } else {
             createWarning();
        }
    }

    private void createWarning(){
        int LAYOUT_FLAG;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
        } else {
            LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
        }

        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LAYOUT_FLAG,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.dimAmount = 0.3F; // darkens the background

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        // inflates warning.xml
        warning = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.warning, null);

        // here you can add the logic to your view
        Button btn = warning.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_warning);
        btn.setOnClickListener((o)->{
            runOnUiThread(()->{
                windowManager.removeView(warning);
            });
        });

        int color = android.graphics.Color.rgb(61, 41, 0);
        warning.setBackgroundColor(color);
        windowManager.addView(warning, params);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is a very good answer. Sorry for so late my respond. But I have a problem: I need to use min 21 sdk version, but this line "android.provider.Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)" requires 23 sdk version. Do you know how to change this line?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the permission is only needed for SDK version 23 and later. I edited the `createWarningWithPermission()` method now. Give it a try.